# 12.04 and Evolution 3.2.3 HTML email rendering issue

Tags: 12.04, evolution, email, html

I've been running the 12.04 release now for a few months and my biggest issue is selecting text (highlighting) in an HTML email that is received in Evolution 3.2.3.

Attempts to select text or hyperlinks in received email causes text to be selected from that point all the way back to the beginning of the email header.  If I forward or reply to the message the newly edited message text selection works fine.  Any fix for this?

Running 12.04 LTS with all current updates as of this writing and using evolution 3.2.3.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evolution/+bug/977541

Yours,
Steffen